# What is the difference in the invocation of 'this' in these examples?

Tags: javascript, this

I'm reading Crockford's 'JS: The Good Parts'. He has two examples using this and I don't understand why in one instance he uses `this` and in another he uses `that`.

The first example:

```
String.method('deentify', function() {
    var entity = {
        quot:   '"',
        lt:     '<',
        gt:     '<'
    };

    return function() {
        return this.replace(/&([^&;]+);/g,
            function (a, b) {
                var r = entity[b];
                return typeof r === 'string' ? r : a;
            }
        );
    };
}());
document.writeln('&lt;&quot;&gt;'.deentify());
```

The second example:

```
Function.method('curry', function() {
    var args = arguments, that = this;
    return function () {
        return that.apply(null, args.concat(arguments));
    };
});
var add1 = add.curry(1);
document.writeln(add1(6));
```

Why can the first example access `this` directly? What is the difference between that example and the one that follows it?

Comment: What is `String.method` or `Function.method`?!

Comment: And also in your first example scope of that immediately executed function is global. Try `console.log(function(){console.log(this)}())` . When you don't pass the scope, it will be global. (`Window` in browser)

Comment: They are custom added helper functions to add methods to the specified prototype; that is Function.method adds a method to the Function prototype, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do `obj.f()`, `this` inside the function `f` will refer to `obj`.

In the first example, `deentify()` is called on a string. In that function, he only needs the object on which the function was called, the string, which is what `this` inside the `deentify()` function is going to refer to.

**Why we need `that`**

The `add1` function needs to store a reference to the original `add` function somehow. `add1` cannot use `this`, because it is *not* called as `add.add1`. This is overcome by creating a closure over `that`, in which he saves the reference to the function you execute `curry()` on (`add()` in the example).

When you call `add.curry()`, `this` will refer to the `add` function. (Because you called `curry()`on `add`). Due to the closure inside the curry function, `that` will keep its value and will still reference the `add` function when `add1()` is called.

If `this` was used inside the function returned from `curry()`, it would refer to the `window` object.

```
Function.method('curry', function() {
    var args = arguments, 
      that = this; //reference to add
    return function () {
        //`apply` calls add
        return that.apply(null, args.concat(arguments)); 
    };
});
var add1 = add.curry(1);
document.writeln(add1(6));
```

**Note**: It is important to see, that the first `return` in the first snippet denotes *the* `deentify()` function, whereas the first `return` in the second snippet denotes the return value *of* the `curry()` function.

If you want to understand the `arguments`/`apply()` magic that makes curry work as well, just ask in the comment, I'll be happy to elaborate.

Comment: Great explanation. Totally makes sense. I should've been placing closer attention to the invocation context. I understand how apply works, but thanks for the offer to explain just the same!

Comment: @Avery I'm glad you like it. Thanks for the feedback.