# Scope of this in javascript function

Tags: javascript

If you have the following code:

```
var global = this;
function A () {
    function B () {
        return this;
    }
    return B();
}
var C = new A();
C === global // true
```

Why does the `this` in function B refer to the global space and not the `this` of the object A?

Comment: In addition to @Pointy's answer, you can see this [technique in practice here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11814953/what-is-the-difference-in-the-invocation-of-this-in-these-examples). (The second code snippet)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of `this` is determined upon every function call. Because `B` is called without any context, the value of `this` is the global object.

It's possible to preserve `this` in an outer context by simply copying it:

```
function A() {
  var x = this;
  function B() {
    return x;
  }
  return B();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`this` has nothing to do with scope, it's not a variable. It's a keyword that evaluates to the currently executing function's object context. The function's object context is determined by how you call it. It doesn't matter where or how the function is defined.

When you call a function like `fn()` then it is not in object context and the language wrongly attempts to work around it when it should just throw an error at the mere sight of `this`. This is somewhat fixed in strict mode where it would evaluate to `undefined`.

When you call a function as a property of some object I.E. `obj.fn()` then `obj` is bound to `this` for that call.

Since it would be clunky having to attach a function to some object just to get the right object context for the call, all functions inherit a `.call` method that allows you to specify the object context explicitly:

```
return B.call(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

To accompany Pointy's correct answer:

The reasoning for this is because you can do whatever you want with functions.
You can return function B from function A, and save it as a global variable.

Or you could append function B as a method to an Object, or a dozen objects.
Or you could use it in an AJAX callback, or use it as a callback from a timer.

Because the engine doesn't know what's going to happen with function B, the language says that `this` refers to whatever the function is being called on, at the time it's called.

This adds a lot of dynamism to the language, but it also adds a lot of headache, if you're not sure what "this" is pointing to at any given time.

Rule of thumb:

If the function is ***directly*** attached as the method of an object, or a function is being called with `.call` or `.apply` and being fed a context, like `myFunc.call(myObj)`, then `this` refers to `window`.

Comment: Thanks to all that replied. I really appreciate your time. I understand now.