# How to Call This Anonymous Javascript Function?

Tags: javascript

```
 var avg = function() 
   {
     var sum = 0;
      for (var i = 0, j = arguments.length; i < j; i++) 
        {

           sum += arguments[i];
         }
      return sum / arguments.length;
   }
```

When I try to call this like:

```
var average = avg(2,3,5);
average; // It works fine;
```

But how do I call it without assigning to a variable?
If anybody can give any suggestion it will be delightful..Thanks.

Comment: Are you experimenting in a JavaScript console and want to see the result?

Answer (score 2):

You'd simply call it like this:

```
avg(2, 3, 5);
```

If you want to see the result, put it in an alert call:

```
alert( avg(2, 3, 5) );
```

Comment: Thanks, for your Suggestion . Can You tell me how to Use this function like a javascript Closures.

Comment: I'm sorry. What exactly do you mean by "javascript closures"?

Comment: function makeAdder(a) {
    return function(b) {
        return a + b;
    }
}
x = makeAdder(5);
y = makeAdder(20);
x(6);// I mean this Javascript closures , I don't know exactly what it's name.Maybe I wrong!!!

Comment: You could call this "hardcoded currying", i.e. partial application of parameters. [The second snippet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11814953/what-is-the-difference-in-the-invocation-of-this-in-these-examples) allows you to curry any function.

Comment: @HumayounKabir I see what you mean. You'd do it like this: http://jsfiddle.net/MAqP3/

Comment: @David:hmmm... Thanks david,I am  new in javascript.Can you tell me how may i know advance topics of modern javascript. Thanks... I must tell you  r an expert javascript coder!!!

Comment: @HumayounKabir Well, there's a good book made on the language (JavaScript, The Good Parts by Douglas Crockford): http://www.amazon.com/JavaScript-Good-Parts-Douglas-Crockford/dp/0596517742

Comment: @HumayounKabir or use the code from the link I provided, which works with *any* function, you don't need to write it anew for every function you want to use it for.

Comment: @HumayounKabir Can you accept my answer by clicking on the check mark next to it? It helps a lot! :)

Comment: @David What is the purpose of this closure of yours apart from sticking it into a closure? It does not even do partial application, it simply defers execution which makes no sense for this code.

Comment: @phant0m You're right. There shouldn't be that extra closure now that I think about it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to put the result from calling the function in a variable, you can do whatever you like with it.

For example, use it as the value in an alert:

```
alert(avg(2,3,5));
```

You can use it in another expression:

```
var message = "The average is " + avg(2,3,5);
```

You can use it directly in another call:

```
someFunction(avg(2,3,5));
```

You can even throw the result away by not doing anything with it, even if that's not useful in this specific situation:

```
avg(2,3,5);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't put the result into a variable or in a compatible context, this function cannot output anything, which makes it difficult to use unless you make it output the result. Try this :

```
var avg = function() 
   {
     var sum = 0;
      for (var i = 0, j = arguments.length; i < j; i++) 
        {

           sum += arguments[i];
         }

      var retvalue = sum / arguments.length;
      consoloe.log("avg: "+retvalue);
      return retvalue ;
   }
```

Then it may help you to see whenever the function is called or not.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand the concept of expressions.

Every expression as a whole represents *one* value. An expression can be made up of multiple subexpressions that are combined in some manner (for example with operators) to yield a new value.

For instance:

- `3` is an expression (a literal, to be specific) that denotes the numeric value three.
- `3 + 4` is an expression, made up of two literal expressions, that as a whole yields the value 7

When you assign a *value* to a variable – as in `var average =` – the right hand side of the `=`-operator needs to be an expression, i.e. something that yields a value.

As you have observed, `average` will have been assigned the value five. It thus follows, that `avg(2, 3, 5)` must itself be an expression that evaluated to the value `5`.

`average` itself is an expression, denoting the current value of said variable.

The most important thing to take away from this is, that `avg()` is in no way connected to `var average =`. `avg()` stands on its own, you can just think it like an ordinary value such as `5` (there are other differences of course).

If you have understood the concept of expressions and values, it should be clear that if you can do

```
var average = avg(2,3,5);
average; // It works fine;
```

You can also do

```
avg(2,3,5);
```